# PROTRACTOR: Integrate jasmine-spec-reporter in slack?

Tags: testing, protractor, slack, jasmine-spec-reporter

I installed jasmine-spec-reporter to replace the default DOT reporter.

Everything is great running, but I want to send the texts I'm seeing in the terminal directly to slack. What is the payload that I should send to slack? and is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [slack-cli](https://github.com/candrholdings/slack-cli) to send your test output to slack.

For example, if your test command is `jasmine`, something like that should do the trick (not tested):

```
$ jasmine | slackcli -t slack_token -g group_name -c
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a custom integration from slack incoming webhook app.
Copy the webhook url which variants on which channel you want to post the output.

Then in protractor conf.js add the following

```
 projectName: ' ',
    environment: 'TEST',
    slackUrl: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1J252SLS/',
    channel: '#autotests'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use npm [jasmine-slack-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-slack-reporter) package for this.

1. Before that you should have your slack webHook url.
   refer this for [incoming slack webhook](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115005265063-Incoming-webhooks-for-Slack)
2. Finally update your config file like this.

```js
    exports.config = {
      seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
      specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
      capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
      },
      onPrepare: function () {
        var webRep = require('jasmine-slack-reporter');
        browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
          var browserName = config.capabilities.browserName;
          jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new webRep.WebReporter({
            projectName: 'Project 1',
            environment: 'Stage',
            slackUrl: "YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL",
            channel: '#dashboard-standup'
          }));
        });
      },
    };
```